# Received a job offer 4 weeks ago with no further contact

Tags: job-offer

I received a job offer 4 weeks ago. I signed it, the back ground check and drug screening have been done and it's been over a week. My tentative start date was a week ago (14th September). I have emailed HR and the response I got was to check with my coordinators.

How should I approach this via email?

Comment: Please describe what "*tentative*" mean here. What is your actual starting date is subject to?

Comment: This is really not a duplicate of the question it has been marked as, and the answers there are really not relevant to someone who already received a job offer.

Comment: @Carson63000 I've edited the question language-wise and cast the final reopen vote but ideally the OP would step in to provide further details. Sadly Christina hasn't been on the site since asking the question.

Comment: If that happened to me, I would be on the phone days before the tentative start date to get information

Answer (score 10):

> How should I approach this via email?

You shouldn't.

You need to speak to someone on the phone, not send an email and hope it gets answered. It's already a week beyond the supposed tentative start date they gave you, and you haven't gotten a satisfactory explanation in response to the email you sent already. This is not the time to be sending more emails.

Phone HR, ask them what's going on. Ask if there are any problems or hold-ups regarding your background check etc. If they give you another non-response like "I'll check with my coordinators" ask them to call you back straight away after doing so.

If it's a large HR department make sure you make a note of the name of the person you speak to, so if you do have to call back chasing, you can say who was supposed to be looking into it for you.